# Android setTheme with resources from another application at runtime

Tags: android, themes

I would like to be able to set the theme of my app at runtime using resources from a "theme apk" (another Android application). I'm pretty sure this is not possible, as Activity.setTheme(int resid) doesn't take in enough information to load resources from another package file. However, I'm asking the question to save someone else the time I've spent searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `Context` for a given package name with `Context.createPackageContext(String, int)`. However, even though you can access that package's resources, you can't do it by directly using ids, but only by full name.

Comment: I can already access the resource drawables of another application and have used them in mine. However, I'm not sure how to do that with themes.